# How to save user preferences in Google desktop gadget?

Tags: preferences, google-desktop

I want to save the user preferences in a Google Desktop Gadget.
I am not able to find any documents for it.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured it out myself!

"options" are used to store user preferences in google desktop gadget.
More details could be found here:
http://code.google.com/apis/desktop/docs/gadget_apiref.html#options

Here is an example of how to use it:

> To get value: options.getValue("checkboxa");
>   To save value: options.putValue("checkboxa", "ON");

More details could be found here:
http://google-desktop-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OptionsDialog/main.js

Hope this was helpful.

Thanks,
happyhardik